# Sending an email from Sendy to Outlook changes font size

Tags: html, email, outlook, font-size, sendy

I'm having a problem with my emails that I'm sending from Amazon's Sendy service. I'm sending simple text email and set the font size to 10.5px in the html but when I then send out the emails they end up in my inbox at font size 8...

Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Sendy is configured to send emails in plain text. For example, you can configure this option in Outlook:

[image]